# How to search on Google with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm really new to web scraping. Is there anyone that could tell me how to search on google.com with Selenium in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to search something on `google`, try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.google.com/')

textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name=\"q\"]')

textbox.send_keys('who invented python\n')
```

Comment: Hey, @Sushil I tried the code but this error occoured:
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input"}`

It might be something with the fact that the Cookie Alert pops up?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Selenium, there are other tools more suitable for that. Be aware that Google does not look upon favorably on scraping their search results:

> Google does not take legal action against scraping, likely for
> self-protective reasons. However, Google is using a range of defensive
> methods that makes scraping their results a challenging task.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_scraping

Comment: What other tools would you recommend?

Comment: I never used it, but https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy, https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-scrapy looks worthwile to try. But also BeautiulSoup should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium probably isn't the best. other libraries/tools would work better. BeautifulSoup is the first one that comes to mind

Comment: Thank you I'll look into that